# Exceptions in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I am developing an mobile application using j2me.In that i am using kxml parser.In my application i have to call an url to get the data.When i am calling that url sometimes it showing:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: update of non-existent node   Exception.
```

My sample code is:

```
 InputStreamReader isr=null;
        InputStream rssStream=null;
        InputStream is = null;
        HttpConnection conn=null;
        try
        {          
            conn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(rssUrl);           
            rssStream = conn.openInputStream();---------->I think exception is shown here.         
            isr = new InputStreamReader( rssStream );
            parser.setInput(isr);
            parser.nextTag();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you replace the code

```
 rssStream = conn.openInputStream();---------->I think exception is shown here.         
 isr = new InputStreamReader( rssStream );
```

with the following code

```
isr = conn.openInputStream();
```

Then try it.

Answer (score 0):

The XML content returned by rssUrl is probably mal-formed. Download the content to a local file and check it.

If it is mal-formed, can you change the url content?